# Referencing Source Files of Shared Libraries in Valgrind

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, shared-libraries, valgrind

We have a software project which has the primary purpose of providing a library and API.  We also provide example programs and utilities that use this library.

So, let's say that I have built and installed our library.  When I run valgrind on one of the example / utility programs, I obviously see references to functions in the library.  The issue is that it doesn't provide line numbers, and I would like it to.

Is there a way to tell Valgrind to reference source files that aren't obviously part of an executable, but are part of the source code for a library that is linked-in to the executable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are compiling shared library with `-g` to add debug information. This should be enough for Valgrind to reference source files. See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful for more information.